# duplicated compiled classes in tailwind (scss)

Tags: html, sass, gulp, tailwind-css, vite

i installed the project starter twice one with "vite" and once with "gulp" yet i encountered the same issue.
when compiling the tailwind code the utility classes after the @apply compiles in seperate class as show in the image.
i am using tailwind 3.2.1 if this might help

[image]

i tried as mentioned to change from vite to gulp as a friend suggested yet nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm your issue using `vite build`. However as your question does not contain build script example and problem took place both in Vite and Gulp I will assume you have issue using Tailwind Cli (as I can reproduce it using `npx tailwindcss -i input.scss -o output.css`) command only. In such case you need to change two things

1. As you're using nested syntax you need to add `tailwindcss/nesting` plugin into PostCSS configuration file

```js
// postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {}, // should be placed BEFORE tailwindcss
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
};
```

*P.S. Not sure why does it requires though. I think because Tailwind is PostCSS plugin it does nothing about `.scss` files and immediately skips all SASS-features (like nested syntax) and proceeds your file as regular CSS file using PostCSS. As nested syntax is not supported by CSS you need to include required PostCSS plugin for that (which is `tailwindcss/nesting` in this case)*

2. Add `--postcss` flag to your build command (it will tell you're using custom PostCSS configuration)

```bash
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.scss -o ./dits/output.css --postcss
```

Now you should see expected output